# Using JSP with PhoneGap

Tags: jsp, cordova

Is it possible to use JSP files with phonegap?

I've linked my root index.html to a JSP file. I am getting a response on the android device that shows all of the text in between brackets

I'm just looking for a simple confirmation that it is possible or not. Sorry for any vagueries, but if it is possible, my assumption is that it is a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap only allows HTML/CSS/JS files to be run in the package. You can make an Ajax call to your .jsp file on a server but that is about it. See the last answer in [this](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/) Q/A.